# Outlook 2010 broken rules dialog

Tags: windows-7, rules, outlook-2010

I've rebuilt my machine and have transfered my Outlook 2010 installation across to the new machine using BackupRex (http://backsettings.com/outlook-backup.html)

Everything has worked fine except that I can't see/edit any of my rules. Every button on the dialog is disabled

[Screenshout Outlook rules http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/43b6bc8ddf.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/43b6bc8ddf.jpg)

I've tried scanning the PST using the ScanPST tool but it's not found anything. Any ideas?

I'm running this on Windows 7 now instead of Windows XP

I've also tried outlook /cleanrules but it's not made a jot of difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted the profile and recreated it. The rules dialog works correctly. Clearly it's something odd with the way transfered the installation.